# call a javascript function from itself

Tags: javascript, function

I have a javascript function similar to this

```
function myFunction(){
    // *** WOULD LIKE TO CALL changeColor HERE *** //
    this.changeColor = function(){
    };
}
```

Like the comment says I would like to call changeColor

I tried this.changeColor() and a few other variations but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why changeColor must be inside myFunction? And what happens if define changeColor whitout this and then call it?

Comment: If the call is made within `myFunction()`, then you just call `changeColor`

Comment: Just call this.changeColor() after you do the assignment. Piece of cake.

Comment: You cannot call changeColor before it has been defined through your assignment `this.changeColor = function...`. At the location of your comment changeColor is still undefined.

Answer (score 4):

To run a function, just write it as:

```
function myFunction(){
  // referencing to the function
  changeColor();
  function changeColor() {
    // here would be the code!
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function myFunction(){
    this.changeColor = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(){
    //your code
}
```

to call the function you can do:

```
var myfunction = new myFunction();
myfunction.changeColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you might do, but it sounds like the key is understanding how "this" works, and how to scope it.  Consider the following:

```
function initialClass() {

    // private members (closures)
    var _color = "blue";
    function privateMethod() {
        alert(this.color());
    }

    // public members
    this.color = function (vInput) {
        if (vInput === undefined) {
            return _color;
        }
        else {
            _color = vInput;
            privateMethod.call(this);
            return;
        }
    };

    }

    function partialClass() {

    // private members (closures)
    var _size = "large";

    // public member
    this.size = function (vInput) {
        if (vInput === undefined) {
            return _size;
        }
        else {
            _size = vInput;
            return;
        }
    };

    }

    var oMyObject = new initialClass();
    partialClass.call(oMyObject);

    oMyObject.color('orange');
    oMyObject.size();
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are trying to make objects:

```
function myFunction(){
    function changeColor(){
    };
    changeColor();
    // *** WOULD LIKE TO CALL changeColor HERE *** //
    this.changeColor = changeColor;
}
```

You now can do something like:

```
var test = new myFunction(); // calls changeColor
test.changeColor();
```

Answer (score -3):

Try assigning it to a variable like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    var changeColor = function(){
        changeColor();
    };
    this.changeColor = changeColor;
}
```

Comment: The `changeColor` function will never end! It will recurse into infinity :-)

Comment: I thought it was obvious that you would have to add an "if" and make it conditional. It's an example of how to do the recursion, not an example of how to implement the underlying problem which wasn't specified.